# Find last day of previous month data in sql

Tags: java, mysql

```
String sql= "select amount,\n"+ "Temperature,\n"+ "Density\n"+
    "from sheet\n"+ "where Code=? and product=? and and month(date)=? && year(date)=? ";

PreparedStatement stmt=DBConnectionDATABASE.prepareStatement(sql);

try {
    stmt.setString(1, get.Code());
    stmt.setString(2, get.Product());
    stmt.setInt(3, get.month());
    stmt.setInt(4, get.Year());
```

how can i find the last day of previous month with data .

Comment: you want to set parameter of last day of previous month ,am I right?

Comment: yes , i need to find last day of previous month data from sql

Comment: You mean the exact last day of previous month or just the last day with data in the previous month?

Comment: last day with data in the previous month

Comment: Okay, see my answer, this should work for you. I think the biggest "open" part is the calculation of the first second on the first day of the current month. But you should be easily figuring this out alone ;)

Comment: I still have problem , I don't know what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this query

```
select max(date) from sheet where date between ? and ?
```

this will return the maximum date between the date range

then

```
select * from sheet where date=(select max(date) from sheet where date between ? and ?);
```

I am well aware that its not ethical to use aggregate functions without `group by` but it works in this case.

Answer (score 1):

1. Compare the date with less: `where ... date<?`
2. Set the parameter to the beginning of the next month, which you can calculate from the month and year you got, see [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)
3. Order the query by date desc: `where ... order by date desc`
4. If you really want only the last entry than limit the query: `where ... order by ... limit 1`

The whole query could look like this:

```
select amount, Temperature, Density from sheet where Code=? and product=? and date < ? order by date desc limit 1
```

Comment: so what should i put here stmt.setDate(3, ???????????);

Comment: @Adrian strictly speaking you should check that the date is after the start of the previous month too - there might not be any records in that month at all.

Comment: @user1699623 The first second of the next month, for instance if you want july than set the first second of August 1st in it.

Comment: @Alnitak Yep, you are right, but simple enough to figure it out alone, if really needed.

Answer (score 1):

String sql= "select amount,\n"+ "Temperature,\n"+ "Density\n"+ "from sheet\n"+ "where Code=? and product=? and day(date)=? and month(date)=? && year(date) =? " and set parameters

Comment: thanks it was usful but how can i find the last day of previous month with data

Comment: Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   int year = 2012;
   int month = 1;
   int day = 0;
   cal.set(year, month,day);
   day = cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
day will be 31

Answer (score 0):

To get last day of previous month

```
    SELECT DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH( CURDATE( ) ) 
DAY ) AS  'last_date'
FROM dual
```

then last_date as your query string date parameter

String sql= "select amount,\n"+
                "Temperature,\n"+
                "Density\n"+
                "from sheet\n"+
                "where Code=? and product=? and date=? ";

Answer (score 0):

int year = 2012;
int month = 1;
int day = 0;
cal.set(year, month,day);
Date date = cal.getTime();

set this date to your query
 this will give jan 31 2012

if you give month =2 it will give feb 29 2012 and so on

Comment: i get error by cal.set(year, month,day);

Comment: This won't work as you still have to match the hours, minutes, seconds.. of the date within the db and the date you provide for comparison.

Comment: use this 
String sql= "select amount,\n"+ "Temperature,\n"+ "Density\n"+
    "from sheet\n"+ "where Code=? and product=? and day(date)=? and month(date)=? && year(date) =? "
and set parameters

Comment: @nagarajub You should add this as separate answer.